# Ripple is drawn below ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-5.0-lollipop, ripple

I have an `ImageView` and a `CheckBox` inside a `FrameLayout`. Although the `CheckBox` is placed above the `ImageView`, its ripple feedback is drawn below the `ImageView`. Is there any way to draw the ripple on top? Tried adding elevation values but nothing changed.

[image: example]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView

    android:layout_height="285dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the ripples are drawn on top of their container's background. So I put the CheckBox in another container, set the container's background to transparent and the ripple showed up correctly.

Comment: Would you mind positing the code?  Also have you been able to get ripples working on API versions less than 21?

Comment: @AG1 to get ripples below API 21 then you need to use some library. There is an awesome library [here](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)